# Problem in panel of Django3.0 after migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Why is the error appearing in django/admin? Migrations ok, I need to have 3 items in the table where I will have results.

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    """Robot model, speed and position simulation"""
    product = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOOSE)
    velocity = models.FloatField()
    positionX = models.FloatField()
    positionY = models.FloatField()
    angleTHETA = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:`enter code here`
        verbose_name = "Robot"
        verbose_name_plural = "Robots"

    def __str__(self):
        resum = self.get_product_display()
        return resum
```

---

ProgrammingError at /admin/robot/robot/
column robot_robot.velocity does not exist
LINE 1: ...LECT "robot_robot"."id", "robot_robot"."product", "robot_rob...

====
Hello, can someone help me with the above problem, I keep getting this error:
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "robot_cleanrobot" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "robot_cleanrobot"

1. first migrations done
2. then pip install -r requirements.txt
3. python manage.py startapp
4. settings
5. makemigrations & migrate
6. add model
7. register a view

nothing helps me, I have done many times from scratch, even deleted the whole directory and also nothing,

I changed the model in the new project and nothing

---

At the beginning it worked ok for the first time, but when I added the float it all went down - I do not know what to do about it. Please help. Thx.

```
class CleanRobot(models.Model):
    """..."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "CleanRobot"
        verbose_name_plural = "CleanRobots"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

=================================
Ok, not working: ok step by step what i am doing:

1. i create a django project
2. enable (venv)
3. makemigrations
4. migrate
5. pip install -r requirements.txt
6. copy to settinigs_local project
7. python manage.py start app
8. change settings - add code -> reference to local + register application
9. add code to models
10. register models
11. makemigrations
12. migrate
13. runserver
14. dajngo/admin
    ... +Add is ok, by name entering I get error... I have other projects on my computer and they work normally... I have other projects on my computer and they work normally... not today I have deleted the whole folder for the 20th time...

Comment: Did u use  migrate?  if yes then u  python manage.py migrate --fake   use this,  if not , then use normal migrate

Comment: yes I did, only when in the admin panel I want to add something there is an error.... there are no errors during migration

Comment: not working
python manage.py migrate --fake / 
python manage.py migrate ..zero / 
python manage.py migrate  / 

but I get this message which I don't know what to do with after selecting 1?.
It is impossible to add a non-null field 'angleTHETA' to a robot without specifying a default value. This is because the database needs something to populate the existing rows. Please choose the fix:
 1) Specify a one-time default value (it will be set in all existing rows with null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define the default value in the models.py file.
Select the option:

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the database fields that you requested probably do not exist. Remember to run both [`makemigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) and [`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemigrations) commands.

As @ElvinJafarov suggested, migrate the database before proceeding. You get the message about `angleTHETA` field because of constraints on the database - that’s completely normal. As stated in the message "*This is because the database needs something to populate the existing rows*".

At this point you can quit and manually define the default value in the models.py (press 2 in message prompt). After this change your `Robot` by setting a field default, so that Django can populate DB with the default value, e.g.:

```
angleTHETA = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

You can also change DB constraints by allowing it to have empty values.

```
angleTHETA = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

In general, I advise you to read [the documentation on migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/migrations/).

### Update 1:

From your description it seems that first you ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands, and then created the model. It should be the other way around - first make the model, then run `makemigrations`. If it went well you should see something like this

[image]

and also you should have a new non-empty file in your app's `migrations` folder. Then run `migrate` command. You should see something like:

[image]

If something went wrong, post the message you did get.

Comment: Hello, can someone help me with the above problem, below in the code I have added the description once again. I added another model and it doesn't work either

Comment: What's more in django/admin when I click on a name I get an error and when I click +Add it's ok, helpppp, I'm going crazy ;) :///

Comment: It is not working, I have added step by step what I am doing....

Comment: Works:
I don't know which of these things worked but:
1. i had alpha name and alpha project name so i changed to alphaapp,
2. after migration 2 I created a new superuser 

Maybe this will be useful for someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

Works:
I don't know which of these things worked but:

1. i had alpha name and alpha project name so i changed to alphaapp,
2. after migration 2 I created a new superuser

Maybe this will be useful for someone ;)